# Shopify API: Get Orders limit

Tags: json, api, shopify

i am receive only 18 orders and also if i set the limit property I get only 18 orders back.

```
admin/orders.json?limit=50
```

And if i use the page property

```
admin/orders.json?limit=50&page=2
```

it returns empty orders.

```
{"orders":[]}
```

After some more searching i found out that this works

```
admin/orders/search.json?query=&limit=122
```

but is not mentioned in the API, and is not implemented in the Python SDK

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone cares, you can find this API reference here : http://docs.shopify.com/api/order